# Cannot push to GitHub: Gist does not support directories

Tags: git, github, directory, gist

I get this error when trying to push a Gist with folders in it to GitHub:

```
remote: Gist does not support directories.
remote: These are the directories that are causing problems:
remote: dirname1, dirname2
```

Looking at other questions, it seems that GitHub Gist doesn't accept empty folders, but none of these folders are empty.
I can successfully push other files that are inside the root folder of the repository, and can also successfully deploy the app to Heroku using Git.

How do I add a directory to GitHub's Gist? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: So what is your exact question?

Comment: @simpe sorry .. the question is how do i add directories or what i am doing wrong that is preventing me from adding directories ?

Comment: You likely want to push to github, not the gist page. Can you post the address of the repo to which you're pushing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not possible, use a repository. Gists are only for files.

Comment: Please, copy here the comment. Sorry, that page doesn’t exist!

Comment: "If you have a bunch of Gists that need to be grouped together, is there any reason that you're not turning these Gists into a repository or a series of repositories?" - https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Can-you-create-groups-in-GitHub-to-differentiate-what-the-gists/td-p/6630

Comment: Yes, oftentimes because it isn't directly re-usable but still needs multiple directories. What a shame.

Comment: Although the referenced tweet has been deleted, the "comment of a github developer" no doubt refers to the [_reply_](https://twitter.com/holman/status/297476115176517632) by [Zach Holman](https://zachholman.com/): "Gists are for files, repositories are for directories."

Answer (score 4):

You cannot create folders, but you can have each "gist" begin with a prefix. So you can assign each gist to a "domain" or a "folder". If you want to search in a certain "folder" or "domain", you only have to enter the prefix.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to work around Gist's prohibition on directories: only the *latest* commit on each branch is checked for the presence of directories. If you create a commit with directories, then remove the directories in the next commit, you can push both commits together, then create a link to the commit with directories by appending `/[commit]` to the Gist URI.

The Gist UI handles this a bit weird: it seems to flatten out the directory structure, and display files across all directories. You *can* push branches, but branches other than `master` aren't linked to in the Gist UI anywhere. Commit URIs still work correctly though.